# pig not processing the input but the MR job is success in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Here is my pig script to do word count:

```
book = LOAD '/data/pg5000.txt' using PigStorage() as (lines:chararray);
words = foreach book generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(lines)) as word;
words_grouped = group words by word;
words_agg = foreach words_grouped generate group as word, COUNT(words);
words_sorted = ORDER words_agg BY $1 DESC;
STORE words_sorted into '/output/result_pig' using PigStorage(':');
```

After I start the job, `pig wordcount.pig`, the job completes successfully. The results are in 
HDFS. But the console shows the following: (the job is success but total records written and read is 0)

```
HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.2.0   0.12.2-SNAPSHOT sridhar 2014-07-07 11:30:50 2014-07-07 11:31:36 GROUP_BY,ORDER_BY

Success!

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTIme  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_local1242482660_0003    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   words_sorted    ORDER_BY    /output/result_pig,
job_local27414860_0002  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   words_sorted    SAMPLER 
job_local490629346_0001 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   book,words,words_agg,words_grouped  GROUP_BY,COMBINER   

Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records from: "/data/pg5000.txt"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "/output/result_pig"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local490629346_0001 ->  job_local27414860_0002,
job_local27414860_0002  ->  job_local1242482660_0003,
job_local1242482660_0003


2014-07-07 11:31:36,288 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
```

Comment: from logs, you are running in local mode "job_local*". Does this file exist in local file system? /data/pg5000.txt and if yes, is there data in file?

Comment: @rVr: there is data in file and it is not in local file system. There is no directory structure /data/pg5000.txt in my local but   is present in HDFS. if there is no data, how can I see the results on the HDFS.

Comment: exactly my point, looks like job is running locally, can you create a file locally and give its path as input and see if it runs? or make sure you are running pig in mapreduce mode by using this command $pig -x mapreduce